# When is it safe to close the InputStream used by PreparedStatement.setBlob?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

`PreparedStatement.setBlob`, `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream`, and a handful of other `PreparedStatement` methods can read data for the query from an `InputStream`.  Unfortunately, the documentation is not at all clear on *when* the data is read.  All it states is that

> data will be read from the stream as needed until end-of-file is
>   reached.

I can think of three possible interpretations for when the data is needed:

- Before the call to setBlob (or other method that has an `InputStream` parameter) returns
- When the statement is executed
- When the transaction is committed

So, at what point is it safe to close the `InputStream` (or other resources which the `InputStream` in question depends upon)?  Does it depend on the driver (I'm currently using `MySQL`, but as I like to keep open the possibility of migration it might be nice to know how other drivers treat this, too)?

Comment: As an aside, my code currently assumes that the stream can be closed once the statement is executed, and appears to work correctly, but I don't see how I can be sure that it will always work.

Answer (score 2):

Wrote up a quick example to test this out locally w/MySQL(excuse the bad exception handling):

```
public void testInputStream(String filePath) throws SQLException, IOException {
    DBUtil util = new DBUtil();//just a simple connection util
    Connection conn = util.getConnection("test");

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    String sql = "insert into testtable(scol,lob) values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, "number4!");
    stmt.setBlob(2, fis);
    //fis.close() //this throws an exception
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    fis.close();//no exception here
    conn.commit();
    //fis.close();//no exception when called here
    stmt.close();
}
```

testtable is a very simple table:

```
create table testtable (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    scol varchar(50),
    lob blob
)engine=innodb;
```

After the statement is executed seems to be the correct answer from my testing as well. There might be ways it would vary across drivers but I don't think any scenario would work where you close the `InputStream` before the the query is executed. After poking through the source code of MySQL's [PreparedStatement](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java.html) it looks pretty straight forward; it needs the stream open to call `sendPacket()`(under the hood method that does the actual execution) but after `executeUpdate()` is finished the stream objects appear idle.

I think you'd be safe to assume this behavior is consistent across *nearly* any driver that implements the JDBC spec. Could be some exceptions there but if they support `InputStream` it should work the same way.

Comment: It definitely appears to work *currently*, but my question is more along the lines of "how safe am I to assume a particular answer to this question?"  I'm worried, for instance, that a future update to the JDBC driver or change of DBMS will break the code.  I was hoping there was some behaviour specified somewhere other than the API Javadoc that I've missed.